# How to pass string literals on onclick function in blazor?

Tags: blazor

I have the following code:

```
 <MudPaper Class="d-flex flex-row pt-6 pb-4" Style="height:100px;" @onclick="View">
               
 </MudPaper>

   private async Task View()
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/someurl");
    }
```

This works properly.

If I have to pass parameters to the function how would I do that. I tried the following :

```
<MudPaper Class="d-flex flex-row pt-6 pb-4" Style="height:100px;" @onclick="View("someurl")">
               
 </MudPaper>

   private async Task View(string url)
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/"+url);
    }
```

obviously at this place its throwing errors.

`@onclick="View("someurl")">`

I tried replacing with single quotes, doesnot work either

Comment: `@onclick="@(() =>View("someurl"))"`

Comment: @Venkat, just a comment to add to what the others have said: in a lambda expression, you can catch tthe event if you want to, as well: `@onclick="(args)=> View("someurl", args)`, and catch the event args in your method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Replace  `@onclick="View("someurl")"`
with     `@onclick='() => View("someurl")'`

The `'` quotes are not essential but make it easier to read.